# What does this Ping answer mean?

Tags: windows, networking, ip, ping

This is the output from an attempt to ping from a Windows 7 computer with an LTE modem plugged in.

The LED on the device tells me that the device has a data (IP) connection, but the Windows network adapter is not connected, and internet access is not possible.

Can anyone with more Ping or IP experience than me tell me what exactly the Ping result means?
I am guessing that it means that the computer is able to reach another local node - what can I deduce from that?

```
ping 8.8.4.4
Pinging 8.8.4.4 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.80.21.54: Destination host unreachable
Ping statistics for 8.8.4.4:
Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss)
Control-C
^C
```

This is the output from ipconfig for the network adapter:

```
Mobile Broadband adapter Mobile Broadband Connection 2:
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Mobile Broadband Network Adapter (Huawei)
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1E-10-1F-7F-B6
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the device on 10.80.21.54 doesn't know where to send the packets for 8.8.4.4

If that is the IP of your PC check if you have default gateway configured to a correct IP address.

Is your LTE modem a usb stick, or is a device with a LAN port or WiFi you are connected to.

Does your PC netowrk card have the 10.80.21.54 address, do an `ipconfig /all` and paste it here.

Comment: Thanks Alen.  I added the output from ipconfig above - there is no IP address shown.

Comment: There is also no IP address shown for any other network adapter, as they are all not connected.  Could this IP address be the next node in the mobile network?

Comment: do ipconfig /all, it is possible that it is the static ip on you LAN card

Comment: I did do ipconfig /all, don't want to post it all here, as I have clearly not mastered the art of laying it out properly...but there was no static IP address configured for the LAN card (or anywhere else). It occurred to me that this IP address might be the modem, although I have previously understood that the IP connection should end on the computer, and the modem shouldn't have its own IP address.

Comment: The modem is a usb stick with a connection to the LTE network.  It makes an IP connection automatically when you plug the stick in, but you don't get internet access, and I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: Your modem show media disconnected, so it cant be a next IP in the line of that connection as there isn't any connection, did you started the mobile connection in the software of the stick, I don't know about your LTE, but on my Vodafone stick the connection doesn't get started automatically, I have to started it manually

Comment: I guess your stick a UMTS one? Do you know the model, and I could check?  Under UMTS, the IP connection is started manually.  But under LTE, the network sets up an IP connection as soon as you plug the stick in.  The modem is showing that it has a data connection, it is the Windows network adapter that is media disconnected.

Comment: My stick isn't LTE, it is Huawei Mobile Connect E169 HSDPA, I have to start my connection in Vodafone Mobile Connect software, I don't know if your LTE works that way to

Comment: The E169 makes a connection to the UMTS network using 3GPP protocols, and then it makes an IP connection when you click the connect button on the Vodafone software.  But LTE is different - the modem makes an IP connection automatically when the stick is plugged in.  The LED on the stick shows a data connection, but the network adapter in Windows is still media disconnected.  And that's the connection for the ping result above - allegedly an IP connection, but Ping from the computer not possible.

Comment: if that is not an IP on your PC then it is probably a private IP on the LTE modem, I don't know why your modem doesn't make the connection to the Internet, or if it does why it doesn't route your traffic to it from the private side. Didn't use LTE in practice so can't help you there

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your wireless router is not allowing communication between clients. It's common for wireless routers to deny communication between hosts that are connected to it via the WLAN interface. Some wireless routers have options in their setup program to allow/deny communication between clients. Thats what I would check first.

Comment: It is a connection over the mobile network though, not WLAN.  Thanks.